# Bizarre WHERE col = NULL behavior

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, null

This is a problem one of our developers brought to me. He stumbled across an old stored procedure which used 'WHERE col = NULL' several times. **When the stored procedure is executed it returns data.**

If the query inside the stored procedure is executed manually it will not return data unless the 'WHERE col = NULL' references are changed to 'WHERE col IS NULL'.

Can anyone explain this behavior?

Comment: Check the ANSI_NULLS setting.

Comment: Could you provide the entire query?  If, for instance, the `WHERE col = NULL` appeared in a subquery, and the outer query said `NOT IN`, that would be an explanation. (although of course it wouldn't explain why the query works as expected outside the SP.)

Comment: @RBarryYoung: Right!  Put that as an answer? :)

Comment: @RBarryYoung: You were absolutely right. If you post an answer I will mark it. Thanks guys!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's by design: if you compare anything to `null`, it evaluates to `unknown`.  Any logic with `unknown` is itself `unknown`.  So any statement with `anything = null`  will always be false.

The important difference is between these two constructs:

```
1 = null --> unknown
1 is null --> false
```

So:

```
1 = null or 1=1 --> unknown (false)
1 is null or 1=1 --> true
```

So as you can see, `unknown` taints an entire expression.

Based on the comments, a better answer would probably be checking for ANSI_NULLs, with:

```
SELECT SESSIONPROPERTY ('ANSI_NULLS')
```

If this returns `false`, the `= null` construct would work like `is null`:

```
set ansi_nulls on -- default
SELECT SESSIONPROPERTY ('ANSI_NULLS') -- 1
select 1 where not null = 1 -- no rows returned
set ansi_nulls off
SELECT SESSIONPROPERTY ('ANSI_NULLS') -- 0
select 1 where not null = 1 -- returns a row
```

The default is `ansi_nulls on` though, and it's very unusual to see it turned off.  A stored procedure does remember the setting from the time it was created:

```
set ansi_nulls off
go
create procedure dbo.TestNulls as select 1 where not null = 1
go
set ansi_nulls on
exec dbo.TestNulls -- Still prints a row
```

You can check the saved settings by scripting the procedure from SSMS.

Comment: If u downvote, plz provide a reason. Specially if u downvote a *correct* answer...

Comment: @Remus, both of the answers so far are correct FOR SOME OTHER QUESTION.  They both missed that the OP said that the stored procedure was giving data, they only had the problem when they ran the query manually.  I'd really like to see the correct answer to this question.  I've boldened the important point in the question.

Comment: I think the point is that the query is running correctly even with the incorrect syntax.

Comment: The OP clearly understands how NULLs work.  What he doesn't understand is why Col = NULL is returning data when it shouldn't.

Comment: @Lance Roberts: I think a comment would get your point across better than an unexplained downvote?

Comment: So could his SP be running with ANSI_NULLS off, but his manual session running with it on?

Comment: +1 since it looks like your edit was the answer.  Thanks for updating it.

Answer (score 3):

OK, guess I should have made this an answer:

Check the ANSI_NULLS setting

Answer (score 0):

In SQL, `X = NULL` will always evaluate to false, since NULL represents the absence of data, one cannot tell whether it is equal to "another" absence of data or not (`NULL = NULL` is false). This is why the `IS` keyword exists...

Comment: @Etamar, no read the question, and the comment I left on Andomar's answer.

Comment: I understand proper NULL handling. That is not my question.

Comment: Probably because it fails to answer the question, which is why `X = NULL` fails to evaluate to false in the context of the stored procedure.